# Pixi.js: How to Detect end of movie (callback for ended event?)

Tags: javascript, events, video, callback, pixi.js

I have a project where I need to switch between full HD videos in a browser. I realized that my macbooks fans are starting to blow after a while. My assumption was that the video load is a bit too heavy for my browser, so I decided to give [Pixi.js](https://www.pixijs.com/) a try – with the hope that my GPU can handle the videos because I am in a webgl context. If that is wrong in the first place, we can abort here.

Anyway my question:
I load a movie file as a texture and I need to switch back to another movie, whenever that one has ended.

I tried to find some documentation but so far I have not found any callback events. Is there none? Do I have to manually add the total time of the video and then check against
`videoTexture.baseTexture.source.currentTime`?

So far I am switching between videos like this:

I have two different videoTextures and Sprites:

```
const videoTexture1 = new PIXI.Texture.from('video1.mp4');
const videoSprite1 = new PIXI.Sprite(videoTexture1);
videoSprite1.loop = true;
app.stage.addChild(videoSprite1);

const videoTexture2 = new PIXI.Texture.from('video2.mp4');
const videoSprite2 = new PIXI.Sprite(videoTexture2);
videoSprite2.visible = false;
app.stage.addChild(videoSprite2);
```

And then I do:

```
playAndShow(videoTexture2, videoSprite2);
stopAndHide(videoTexture1, videoSprite1);

function playAndShow(texture, sprite) {
  sprite.visible = true;
  texture.baseTexture.source.currentTime = 0;
  texture.baseTexture.source.play();
}

function stopAndHide(texture, sprite) {
  texture.baseTexture.source.currentTime = 0;
  texture.baseTexture.source.pause();
  sprite.visible = false;
}
```

But as I said I now need to detect when my video2 has ended and switch back to video1.

Thank you in advance for any help on this matter.
Cheers

merc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/44283-play-video-in-pixi-v5/?tab=comments#comment-247009

```
    const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('data2/Video/intro/vidA1.webm');
    const videoSprite = new PIXI.Sprite( texture );
    /**@type {HTMLVideoElement}*/
    const videoControler = videoSprite.texture.baseTexture.source;
```

seems that `videoSprite.texture.baseTexture.source` is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement or more specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement

You could use:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime

or other events/properties etc described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement